# How to set the colour of the selction background of an android TextView?

Tags: android, user-interface, android-widget

In the following picture you can see an `android.widget.EditText` (left half) where some text is selected:

[image]

Strange thing is: You can see the start and end marker of the selection but the actual selection is not highlighted.

I wonder what I forgot or what I did wrong here. How can I ensure that the selected area is highlighted using an appropriate background colour?

Comment: @Martin...have you set background to TextView...?

Comment: Indeed I have. If I don't the background would be black which is not what he simulated printer output should be. Is that the problem then?

Comment: yes its the problem. if you are setting background then you should make sure that StateList is taken care of..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a little more experimenting I found the following:

- the colour of the selection background is indeed set by `android:textColorHighlight`.
- The selection is not highlighted when the entry field is in read only mode.

So for me there is nothing to be done about it and i just have to live without a highlighted selection.

Answer (score 1):

for more on StateList, refer this http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#StateList

Comment: Wow, at the end the backgrounds are all 9.png and of course private so you can't use them directly. What a bag of pain.

Comment: Nope, that not the solution. Also I wonder if not `android:textColorHighlight` should be the colour I am looking for. Could it be that the selection is not highlighted in a read only field?